# Application performance Optimization for AppHarbor

Tags: wcf, web, appharbor

My ASP.NET Web site application, which is hosting REST based WCF services and deployed on AppHarbor loads too slow. How can I optimize to get better performance?

Answer (score 0):

.Net applications go in sleep mode when not used a lot. When the first request hits them, it takes a while to get out of 'sleep mode'. That's why I use pindom to 'ping' my sites every minute, to keep everyhting running smooth.

This is after every deploy and application pool recycle.